# Detect full sentence/paragraph with specific word but also including URL using regex

Tags: r, regex

I want to detect full sentences or paragraphs that have specific words. I tried detecting full stops and new lines at the beginning and the end of a sentence, as below.

`([^\r\n.]*(?i)donation[^\r\n.]+|[^\r\n.]*(?i)event[^\r\n.]+)`

```
The event will be held on October 27 at 11:00 a.m. with a reception to follow. To make a donation please visit https://www.example.edu/donate.
```

But it stops when it encounters a "dot" such as in `a.m` or `www.example.com`

I need it to include the dots and URL inside the sentence too.

https://regex101.com/r/0j6o7u/1

Comment: Without a larger example it is hard to know if this is what you want:
`^.*event.*donation.*$`

Answer (score 0):

You can for example start with an uppercase char, match one of the words donation or event, and then match until a dot that is either followed by a space or assert the end of the string.

This pattern is based on the assumption that a sentence starts with an uppercase char and ends with a dot, but that is of course very limited as it all depends on how you would define a "sentence"

```
(?<!\S)[A-Z].*?\b(?:donation|event)\b.*?\.(?= [A-Z]|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O8IQ0C/1)

```
library(stringr)

str <- "The event will be held on October 27 at 11:00 a.m. with a reception to follow. To make a donation please visit https://www.example.edu/donate. This is a test."
str_extract_all(str, "(?<!\\S)[A-Z].*?\\b(?:donation|event)\\b.*?\\.(?= [A-Z]|$)")
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "The event will be held on October 27 at 11:00 a.m. with a reception to follow."
[2] "To make a donation please visit https://www.example.edu/donate."
```